# error during connect: Get http://docker:2375/v1.24/containers/json: dial tcp: lookup docker on 10.0.2.3:53: server misbehaving

Tags: docker, docker-in-docker

yesterday I ran docker in docker using the following command

```sh
$ docker run -it docker
```

It pulled docker and took me to `sh` like `/ #`

I tried to run docker in it and it was working.

But today I did the same thing again and it started giving me an error

```sh
/ # docker container ls
error during connect: Get http://docker:2375/v1.24/containers/json: dial tcp: lookup docker on 10.0.2.3:53: server misbehaving
```

That docker is `20.10` and at start it is running https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/f6a0c427f0354dcf5870c430c72c8f1d6b4e6d5e/20.10/docker-entrypoint.sh file so no need set things from cmd.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but got around it.

We've been binding our host's Docker socket to the container as described in option 2 of https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html#option-2-use-docker-volumes-to-start-the-runner-container (the part `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`).

What was missing was to add the mounted directory to the volumes section of the runner's `config.toml`:

```
[[runners]]
  ...
  [runners.docker]
    ...
    volumes = ["/cache", "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
```

This appearently made the TCP connection unnecessary and the error go away.

Comment: If I am not wrong, this way you are sharing your HOST docker daemon, not using the one in the dind service.

Comment: See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#limitations-of-docker-socket-binding

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this inside Jenkins docker container ensure that the docker:dind image is also up in the docker ps command along with jenkins

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).